# Movie about a man who claims to be an alien

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens, tv

I watched a dubbed movie about a man who claims to actually be an alien from very far away. This man meets with a group of scientists who are interested in what he has to say. The man explains that he uses the energy of light to quickly travel anywhere in space. One of the scientists asks whether he means that he travels at the speed of light, to which the man replies that he does not, as that would mean that he would have to travel for thousands or millions of years from where he is from. In one scene, the man and a group of scientists are in an observatory and the man gives them parameters so that they may turn the telescope towards the man's home system.
I think, during the observatory scene, the other people tell the man to travel to his homeworld and back, after which the man stands in place and says "Adios", followed by "Hello" and claims that he made the trip, much to everyone's amusement. I don't remember anything else, except for the fact that I didn't finish watching the movie.

Comment: I'd be willing to bet that there's more that you can remember. For example, was the alien guy caucasian? What was the budget like? Was the actor famous? What was the alien's name? Was he actually an alien (or just delusional)? Was the film a comedy, horror, scifi? Was it in colour or black & white? What channel did you see it on? There's a good list [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) if you want some prompts for editing in any additional relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the man who claimed to be an alien was white. The film was in color. I don't know if he actually was an alien or delusional. I didn't actually finish watching that movie at the time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is almost certainly "K-PAX", a 2001 movie.

The scene where he 'travels' back and forth using 'Adios' and 'Aloha' (rather than hello) can be seen below:

Answer (score 6):

Possibly K-PAX

K-PAX is a 2001 American-German science fiction-mystery film based on Gene Brewer's 1995 novel of the same name, directed by Iain Softley, starring Kevin Spacey, Jeff Bridges, Mary McCormack, and Alfre Woodard. The film is about a psychiatric patient who claims to be an alien from the planet K-PAX.

At one point he is introduced to a group of astrophysicists who are befuddled when prot displays a level of knowledge about his claimed star system that was unknown to them.

He claims to have journeyed to Earth by means of "light-travel"

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-PAX_(film)